# Odoo 13 TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.dateE

Tags: odoo

class BirthDateAge(models.Model):

```
_inherit = "hr.employee"

birthday = fields.Date(string="DOB")

age = fields.Integer(string="Age")

@api.onchange('birthday')

def _onchange_birth_date(self):

    """Updates age field when birth_date is changed"""

    if self.birthday:

        d1 = datetime.strptime(self.birthday, "%Y-%m-%d").date()

        d2 = date.today()

        self.age = relativedelta(d2, d1).years
```

Error:

```
Odoo Server Error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 619, in _handle_exception

return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 309, in _handle_exception

raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 14, in reraise

raise value

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 664, in dispatch

result = self._call_function(**self.params)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 345, in _call_function

return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/service/model.py", line 93, in wrapper

return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 338, in checked_call

result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 910, in __call__

return self.method(*args, **kw)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/http.py", line 510, in response_wrap

response = f(*args, **kw)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1320, in call_kw

return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1312, in _call_kw

return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 387, in call_kw

result = _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/api.py", line 374, in _call_kw_multi

result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 6070, in onchange

record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/models.py", line 5871, in _onchange_eval

method_res = method(self)

File "/odoo/odoo-server/addons/hr/models/hr_employee.py", line 87, in _onchange_birth_date

('married', 'Married'),

TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.dateE
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Odoo 11, fields of type date and datetime are object of type date or datetime, not string anymore.
So you don't have to use this :

```
d1 = datetime.strptime(self.birthday, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

just use this instead : 
`d1 = self.birthday`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Python datetime module documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

As your error suggest, the first argument of the `strptime` method should be the format string. So just revert your parameters like below.

```
d1 = datetime.strptime("%Y-%m-%d", self.birthday).date()
```

Comment: i have changed and tried again but still showing the same error

Comment: It's because as @m0r7y suggested, Odoo 13 stores date fields as date object. So basically you dont need strptime.

Answer (score 0):

```py
d1 = datetime.strptime(str(self.birthday), "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You will want to add some commentary to explain how this solves the problem and what exactly you have changed and why.

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain what it does and how it helps?

Comment: You can avoid converting the date to `str` then back to `Date`.

Answer (score 0):

`self.birthday` is already of type `Date`, so you do not need to use the `DateTime` module to convert it.

You can reduce you code to one line:

```
self.age = relativedelta(fields.Date.today(), self.birthday).years
```